# Drag Image/Text/File Name onto Firefox Page

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm using Firefox (newest version). I can drag and drop selected text from my text editor into any text area on a webpage. But I can't do that with images, even just to get the file name. Why is this?

Is there any way around it? How does Google do the 'search by image' drop field?

I don't need to be able to drop images, but getting the file name on drop would be a big help.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textareas` are just that: an area of (unstyled) text. Instead, you can drag and drop files onto `<input type="text">` fields, if you don't want to implement your own solution.

Another way to accept files is implementing the [`Drag and Drop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) API, as Google Image Search seems to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Textareas` are for text only. They are not rich text editors that are JavaScript-based that can handle file-drop events.